# How to display a maximum of 4 data in a row?

Tags: excel, vba

Adding to the current VBA code, is there a way to display a maximum of 4 data in a row and the others will fall to the next row?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InvoiceDataGrouping()
    Dim DataSet As Variant, Counter As Long, Dict As Object
  
    'Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary 'Early Binding
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Late Binding
    
    'stores in an array all the data from columns A and B,
    'starting at A1 and up to the last row with data from column B.
    DataSet = Sheets("DO").Range("A1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3)).Value2
  
    For Counter = 1 To UBound(DataSet)
        
        Dict(DataSet(Counter, 1)) = Dict(DataSet(Counter, 1)) _
                                    + " " & DataSet(Counter, 2)
    Next
  
    Sheets("DO").Range("E1").Resize(Dict.Count, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(Dict.keys, Dict.items))
    
    Set Dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Collection rather than a string to hold the invoice numbers. Then loop through the collection creating a string with a maximum of 4 invoices.

Update 1 - sort data

```vb
Sub InvoiceDataGroupingBy4()

    Dim DataSet As Variant, dict As Object, key
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim s As String, rng As Range
  
    'Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary 'Early Binding
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Late Binding
    
    'stores in an array all the data from columns A and B,
    'starting at A1 and up to the last row with data from column B.
    With Sheets("DO")
        lastrow = .Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & lastrow)
        ' sort on col A and B
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add key:=Range("A1"), _
             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            .SortFields.Add key:=Range("B1"), _
             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
         End With
    End With
    DataSet = rng.Value2
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(DataSet)
        key = DataSet(i, 1) ' date
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
             dict.Add key, New Collection
        End If
        dict(key).Add DataSet(i, 2) ' invoice no
    Next
   
    ' reuse DataSet for grouping
    For Each key In dict
        n = dict(key).count ' number of invoices for date
        For i = 1 To n
            s = s & " " & dict(key)(i)
            If (i Mod 4 = 0) Or (i = n) Then
                 r = r + 1
                 DataSet(r, 1) = Format(key, "DD.MM.YY")
                 DataSet(r, 2) = Trim(s)
                 s = ""
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' write re-used part of DataSet to sheet
    Sheets("DO").Range("D1").Resize(r, 2) = DataSet
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! would it be possible to add TEXT(A2,"DD.MM.YY") to format the date?

Comment: @tngxia Is column B a Date or Text format ?

Comment: Column B is a general format, Column A is date format.

Comment: May I know how can add in the vba to sort Column B smallest to largest, then sort Column A oldest to newest, before the Sub?

Comment: @tngxia Ok see update

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather messy function:

```
Function group_array(data As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, count As Byte, ref As String, group As String, id As Long
    
    ' store the first date and set the first group id
    ref = data(1, 1)
    id = 1
    
    ' change the first date to make it unique
    data(1, 1) = data(1, 1) & ":1"
    
    ' make a counter to limit the items to four in a group
    count = 0
    
    ' go through the data array, changing it to build the groups
    For i = 2 To UBound(data)
        count = count + 1  ' increment group count
        If ref = data(i, 1) And count < 4 Then
            ref = data(i, 1)
            data(i, 1) = data(i, 1) & ":" & CStr(id)
        Else ' a new group starts here
            id = id + 1
            count = 0
            ref = data(i, 1)
            data(i, 1) = data(i, 1) & ":" & CStr(id)
        End If
    Next
    group_array = data
End Function
```

You can call it with a line in your original code like this:

```
    ' group the data using the function below
    DataSet = group_array(DataSet)
```